# Jump to a specific location inside nested html

Tags: html

I have a parent search.html and inside that I am including another html search-form.html and attribute.html through ng-include.
Now the inner html search-form.html has another inner html searchresults.html which has a anchor tag onclick of that I want to point to attribute.html which is included in the parent search.html.

My search.html code :

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <!-- Search FORM + RESULTS Panels -->
    <div ng-include="'modules/search/tp/search-form.html'">
    </div>
  
    <div ng-show="isAttributeResultExist()">
        <!--Include ATTRIBUTES PANEL -->
        <div ng-include="'modules/search/attribute.html'">
        </div>
      </div>
```

search-form.html code:

```html
<!--Search RESULTS Tab: Individual-->
<div ng-show="isPersonSearch()">
    <div ng-include="'modules/search/searchresults.html'">
    </div>
</div>
```

searchresults.html anchor tag :

```html
  <a href="#" ng-click="buildDetails(searchResult.person.Id);">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-search fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
```

I want to click the anchor tag inside this searchresults.html and jump to start of attribute.html inside search.html.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your search.html, add an id to the div that loads your attributes.

```
<div id="jumpHere" ng-include="'modules/search/attribute.html'">
```

Normally you could just add that id to an anchor tag on your page and you would jump to that section of the page.

```
<a href="#jumpHere">Jump to section</a>
```

However, it appears that you are using Angular and would need to work in the location into your `buildDetails()` method. You want to use the `$location` service.

```
$scope.buildDetails = function() {
    //other functionality here

    $location.path('jumpHere');
};
```

Comment: Thanks..I ll try that